# Elixir App runs with iex but not when releasing

Tags: elixir, release, elixir-mix

I'm facing the following issue in an Elixir project and I would appreciate any kind of help.

**my_service/mix.exs**

```elixir
def application do
    [
      extra_applications: [:foo_lib],
      mod: {My.Application, []}
    ]
end
```

When I'm running the app using

```elixir
iex -S mix
```

the application runs smoothly. The issue raises up when I'm trying to run my application by creating a release as follows:

```elixir
MIX_ENV=dev mix release
_build/dev/rel/my_service/bin/my_service console
```

After issuing those commands, the execution of the program seems to stuck at the execution of the **foo_lib** and I have to execute by hand

```elixir
My.Application.start(nil,nil)
```

in order to continue the initialization of **my_service**.

Any ideas why I'm facing this strange behavior?

Comment: Please post your whole mix.exs file.  Better yet, post the most basic project with one function that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: not sure, but seems that `console` do not run application, try to run `_build/dev/rel/my_service/bin/my_service start` or `_build/dev/rel/my_service/bin/my_service foreground`